# Field type change issue

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

Hi all I have created a text area(255) field to capture the approval comments entered during an approval/rejection process.

In between it was changed to Text long area(131072) with visible lines as 10.
But while displaying the comments in the field the line number goes beyond 10

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification -  you take offense at the number of displayed lines and think this has something to do with the change of the field type? Is this the question? (At first glance I find the number of "Approved" strings with intermittent "v" more astonishing.)

Comment: @FelixvanHove I read that the visible lines wont be having an affect here it would only show the limited lines ie 10 here before editing the page and not on viewing the record page. So how can I adjust this to a neat format with only 10 lines suppose. Should I have to use VF page?

Comment: visible lines applies to input only; you'll need LWC or VF to introduce a field with scrollbars